# the left hand side of the assignment must be a variable c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
Имею такой код:

 gvEnvironmentGrid.Columns[columnEnvironmentColor].ColumnEdit.EditValueChanged += new EventHandler((object sender, EventArgs e) => {
      var tempColor = sender as ColorEdit;
      colorMatchContent.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => (((Category)r[columnEnvironment]).Id == environmentCategoryGuid)).ForEach(row => (Category)row[columnEnvironment] =
      new Category(environmentCategoryGuid, (string)row[columnEnvironmentName], CategoryShape.Rectangle, tempColor.Color));
      gcTabColorMatchGrid.RefreshDataSource();
      gcTabColorMatchGrid.Update();
  });
```

Но вот имею пролблему с синтаксисом

**the left hand side of the assignment must be a variable c#*

Comment: Что не понятного? С левой стороны присвоения должна быть переменная. (если дословно)

Comment: В переменную присвоить выражение - понятно. В f(x) присвоить сложное выражение - мне сложно догадаться что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: x = f(x) это верно. f1(x) = f2(x) - это не верная запись.